# Syntax for switch-case in Java

Tags: java, syntax, switch-statement

I'm using switch case in Java for the first time and I'm a bit unsure about the syntax. Assuming the setTeamName function works, which it does, would the following function make all of the teams in my array have the placeholder String as it's name or should I from case 0: since i starts at 0?

```
public static Team[] makeTeams(){
    Team[] teams = new Team[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++){
        switch(i){
            case 1: teams[0].setTeamName("Arsenal");
            case 2: teams[1].setTeamName("Arsenal");
            case 3: teams[2].setTeamName("Arsenal");
            case 4: teams[3].setTeamName("Arsenal");
            case 5: teams[4].setTeamName("Arsenal");
            case 6: teams[5].setTeamName("Arsenal");
            case 7: teams[6].setTeamName("Arsenal");
            case 8: teams[7].setTeamName("Arsenal");
            case 9: teams[8].setTeamName("Arsenal");
            case 10: teams[9].setTeamName("Arsenal");
        }
    }
    return teams;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to switch at all here? Why not just `teams[i].setTeamName`

Comment: Oh my! This is an incredibly convoluted way of writing `for (Team team : teams) { team.setTeamName("Arsenal");}` For the syntax of switch, read the Java tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html. Do it for everything else.

Comment: Also make sure you initialise all the array entries first.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense when I think about it, thanks!

Comment: There are better ways to do this. But since you asked the array will be filled from 0 to 8 only here. You should start with 0. Another thing for each case you should have a `break;` statement

Comment: Do you want to set all team names to "Arsenal" ?

Comment: @A_N_Y_R actually, no. Due to the absence of break, all the elements will be initialized after the second iteration, and reinitialized many times after.

Comment: yes it would, because you don't add a `break` statement in each case block. You'll also need curly braces {} then.

Comment: @JBNizet yes for this specific case true. But consider a different case. one initializes and all the other is unnecessary work.

Comment: Another point is that you may not need 10 different `Team` instances. If all the teams are the same you could do. `Team[] teams = new Team [10]; Team a = new Team(); a.setTeamName("Arsenal"); Arrays.fill(teams, a);`

Answer (score 1):

**use break Statement after every instruction in case.**

Answer (score 1):

Your `case` statements would need to start from `0`, because as you rightly observe, `i` starts at zero. However, this appears to be the least of your problems (unless this is just an exercise in using `switch case`).

You don't need `switch case` in this situation at all. Plus, you never create any objects in the array, so every time you attempt to access the array at a particular index, you're going to get a null reference exception. The following will suffice:

```
Team[] teams = new Team[10];
for (int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
    teams[i] = new Team();
    teams[i].setTeamName("Arsenal");
}
```

What you've effectively got in your original example is an example of an anti-pattern, the [Loop-switch sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence). If you want the original example to work properly using this anti-pattern (for educational purposes only), you need to add `break;` statements to ensure that your case statements don't fall through:

```
Team[] teams = new Team[10];
for (int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
    teams[i] = new Team();
    switch (i) {
        case 0: teams[0].setTeamName("Arsenal"); break;
        case 1: teams[1].setTeamName("Arsenal"); break;
        case 2: teams[2].setTeamName("Arsenal"); break;
        case 3: teams[3].setTeamName("Arsenal"); break;
        case 4: teams[4].setTeamName("Arsenal"); break;
        case 5: teams[5].setTeamName("Arsenal"); break;
        case 6: teams[6].setTeamName("Arsenal"); break;
        case 7: teams[7].setTeamName("Arsenal"); break;
        case 8: teams[8].setTeamName("Arsenal"); break;
        case 9: teams[9].setTeamName("Arsenal"); break;
    }
}
```

Without the breaks, every case statement under the one that matches `i` is evaluated, e.g. when `i == 0`, all of the case statements will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of unnecessary work. Try

```
public static Team[] makeTeams(){
    Team[] teams = new Team[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++){
            teams[i] = new Team();
            teams[i].setTeamName("Arsenal");
        }
    return teams;
}
```

Comment: I guess I should have added that not every team will be called Arsenal I was just to lazy to change it yet

Answer (score 0):

You do have options in filling up the array but if your task requires you to use only `switch` then start with `case 0` instead of 1, since 0 is the "first" `case` you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need switch here? `for` loop will be enough.

Switch just move execution to case row and ignore another case for next time. So when you give i = 1 to switch all of the case statement will be executed. You can prevent it by using `break;`

```
switch (i) {
    case 1: 
        teams[0].setTeamName("Arsenal");
        break;
    case 2: 
        teams[1].setTeamName("Arsenal");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few errors in your code:

1) You do not have case 0 - so it is not used. Suggestion is always use default case.

2) Each case should be finished with break; Otherwise all cases below are executed too. For example for case 9 these cases are called 9 and 10. and for case 1 all 10 cases have been called. (but for case 0 in your code none is called).

3) You had reserved array of 10 teams but you did not populated objects to this array. You code will produce null pointer exception.